# How can you repeat a tablix for each record returned from a query?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am generating an SSRS report that is divided into sections, where each section is a separate tablix.

There is a section that should repeat for each instance of an entity. For example: if the report section involves 3 employees, the tablix of type employee should render 3 times, once for each employee.

Note that the number of employees for each report is variable.

Does anyone know of a feature in SSRS or a technique that can support this?

Answer (score 0):

OK this is going to sound really weird but it works.

First you will need to insert a rectangle to the body of your report.

Drag and drop the entirety of the tablix into the rectangle. The tablix should not reside in the rectangle.

Second create a new Tablix and delete all but one column and one row (1X1) tablix.

Drag the rectangle containing the original tablix into the single cell of the new tablix.

You should now have a single cell tablix that contains a rectangle that contains your original tablix.

You can then select the single cell tablix that you created and enter the row group properties for the one row that you have. Add a group expression to group on, in your case, Entity.

You can then go even further and add page breaks between the tablix groups and this will separate the groups on separate pages.